# Name that connector! 16 pin Mini DVR IO

Tags: connector, identification

I purchased a SD-based 4-channel mobile DVR on eBay that did not include the connector one would use to connect reverse lights, turn signals, and other inputs so the DVR can return a relevant camera view to an on-board monitor.

It is similar to a motherboard power connector, but the sockets are smaller and there are 16 pins instead of 20-24.  I had a similar unit where I was able to find a 14-pin PSU connector that got the job done, but even those sockets are too big.

[image: 16pin Connector]
[image: Photo with ruler showing pin pitch]

Comment: What pitch are the pins? Looks like 0.1" - measure from the leftmost pin in a row to the rightmost in the same row and divide by 7 (not 8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will typically find similar looking connectors inside computers for PSU power connectors. However those are the larger Mini-Fit JR style which is 4.2mm pitch.

In this case the 16 pin connector is likely from the smaller Molex Micro-Fit 3.0 style connector, which uses a 3mm pitch connector.

You can find the connector series on the Molex website [here](http://www.molex.com/product/pcb/microfit/microfit.html).

The mating connector will look something like this:

[image: Molex Microfit 3.0 Female 16pin Connector Housing]

There is also the possibility that it is part of the Molex Nano-Fit range which is a 2.5mm pitch. Without an accurate scale or measurement of the pitch it is hard to tell. From a quick scale off the USB connector it is much more likely to be the Micro-Fit above.

For info here is a comparison of the various series within the Molex FiT family of connectors:

[image: Molex FiT Family Comparison]